# Dividing square columns into triangular prisms

Tags: modeling

How do I bisect square-faced columns along their diagonals, so that each square column becomes 4 triangular columns (prisms), thus making each square face into 4 right triangles?
[image: 5x5 square column array]

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to go back a little and erase part of what you have done f you really want them as separate prisms.

Erase all but the bottom faces, search for the operator *Poke Faces* <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and it will automatically break them into triangles.

[image: Prisms]

If you need each triangle extruded as a separate prism you need an additional step **before** extrusion.

Select all diagonals, using the *Select Similar* <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> operator > *Direction* option and then rip the edges with the *Rip* operator <kbd>V</kbd>. Do the same for the opposite direction and the square subdivisions if you had not done so before yet.

[image: Rip Edges]

Then just extrude them back up to create the prisms

Comment: Thanks! However, the 25 columns in the screenshot were each separate objects. I have successfully performed all of your steps on one of the columns, and all of the prism vertices are now present, but it still remains one object. How do I now separate the mesh into 4 new independent objects, each being one of the prisms?

Comment: Enter edit mode i one of the meshes, select all and press `P` *> Separate > Loose Parts*, that should create a bunch of different objects. Have in mind however that unless you specifically need so, that high number of similar objects should probably be turned into clone instances, instead of having a scene full of similar independent objects with duplicate mesh data.